# Using account manager to get OAuth token

Tags: android, oauth

I'm trying to use AccountManager to get Auth token with this code:

```
Account account = ...;
accountManager.getAuthToken(account, "ah", false,
            new AuthTokenCallback(), null);
accountManager.getAuthToken()
```

Is this token valid for OAuth? or is it a different token??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that for OAuth you have to use "oauth2:URL_OF_THE_SERIVE" instead of "ah".

A possible URL of the service (to get user information such as the e-mail address) is: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email