# How to authorize in twitter using android AccountManager?

Tags: android, twitter, accountmanager, scribe, android-account

How to authorize in twitter using android AccountManager?

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accts = am.getAccountsByType(TWITTER_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
if(accts.length > 0) {
    Account acct = accts[0];
    am.getAuthToken(acct, "com.twitter.android.oauth.token"/*what goes here*/, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
        try {
                     Bundle b = arg0.getResult();  
                     Log.e("TrendDroid", "THIS AUTHTOKEN: " + b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));  
                } catch (Exception e) {  
                     Log.e("TrendDroid", "EXCEPTION@AUTHTOKEN");  
                }  
    }}, null);
}
```

Now I got **com.twitter.android.oauth.token** and **com.twitter.android.oauth.token.secret** . But what is the next step? How do I use this to authorize?

I use scribe api and I tried to use it like this:

```
service.signRequest(new Token(token, secret), request);
```

But it doesn't work. Ive also tried another methods which don't work.
There are a lot of questions like this:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4875

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/twitter-development-talk/1tWEx--5h9w%5B1-25%5D

http://osdir.com/ml/twitter4j/2011-06/msg00128.html

[Android: How to Twitter oAuth Through Account Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560609/android-how-to-twitter-oauth-through-account-manager)

[Twitter Authentication through Android's AccountManager classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341164/twitter-authentication-through-androids-accountmanager-classes)

[Using account manager to get OAuth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512230/using-account-manager-to-get-oauth-token)

and no one gives concrete answer

Comment: I don't recommend you moving forward on your app (sorry), because twitter is limiting its access. Read this: Twitter Wants to Stop You from Using Twitter Apps Not Made By Twitter http://gizmodo.com/5935517

Comment: actually I just need user profile data..

Comment: Could you be more specific? What doesn't work? Do you get an error? what's the stacktrace? Have you tried with `scribe` in debug mode? What is the value of `token` and `secret` on that code sample you gave?

Comment: @Pablo, I think the problem is not in scribe... I have `"THIS AUTHTOKEN: " + b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN)` where b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN) is token got by android account manager and I dont know how to use it with scribe to make an authorization to twitter

Comment: Question may be like this: How to authorize twitter using AccountManager and scribe...

Comment: Sorry pal, can't help you there. Don't know a lot about android. If you do have scribe issues please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The `com.twitter.android.oauth.token` and `com.twitter.android.oauth.token.secret` credentials returned by Android's AccountManager only authenticate using Twitter's official Consumer Key and Secret. AFAIK They're not actually useful to third party developers.

With respect to Twitter I'll just say they're out there, and if Twitter changed them via an app update they'd break OAuth for every user without that app update.